# How do I get razz berries in Pokemon: Let's Go?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

How do I get razz berries in *Pokemon: Let's Go*?

I can't buy them from the shop, so I don't know.

Answer (score 9):

You can get them by completing story missions, searching bushes or as a catch reward ([source](https://gamerant.com/pokemon-lets-go-where-to-get-berries/)):

> Getting berries in Pokemon Let’s Go Pikachu and Let’s Go Eevee, outside of the ones that are rewarded to the player during story moments or in other situations, mainly boils down to searching bushes and other parts of the world. Players will know when a bush has a berry in it because their starter Pokemon, whether it be Pikachu or Eevee, will wag their tail when there’s one nearby.
>
> ... players can also get them as catch rewards. Players will be rewarded more berries for the more Pokemon they catch, if they’re getting good throws when catching the Pokemon, and by getting a Catch Combo.

Comment: Also you can get them by doing excellent captures and with a high catch combo makes it more likely to get berries

Comment: As a general note, Pokémon Road is by far the most reliable place to get berries, followed by Cerulean Cave.

Comment: I also believe Pinap Berries will increase the chance of finding berries (and even other items)